# Cannot use [code] with bbpress to display javascript code

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bbpress

I am using BbPress but every time I quote my javascript code to share with someone, it returns page not found.

Example, I put javascript code inside ``:

```
`<script>//this is javascript code</script>`
```

After click submit, it returns "page not found".

but It works with other HTML tag.

Thank for your support.

Comment: Any suggestion, please !

Answer (score 1):

bbPress filters all the content and removes things that are not allowed, and most of the HTML tags are not allowed, and that includes SCRIPT.

Also, bbPress doesn't have `[code]` shortcode and plugins for syntax highlighting usually don't work with bbPress because bbPress has own content processing that needs to be handled differently.

My plugin **GD bbPress Toolbox Pro** has a bunch of shortcodes for bbPress and it includes syntax highlight made for bbPress specifically.